# Android Studio - How to ZipAlign apk

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, apk, zipalign

I have created a signed apk using Android Studio and I'm now going to zipalign it, I have read this:
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/zipalign.html 
but I'm still not sure where to add the lines of code, is it in the Gradle file and where in the file do I add the lines?

Comment: One question, can we zipaligned already signed apk. I'm doing it manually but getting error while installing it, any suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46462718/2624806).

Comment: @CoDe, yes you can. [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/zipalign.html)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Inside you main module's `build.gradle` file you can have multiple build types along with your debug one.

You can specify zipAlign characteristic inside any of your **buildType** by using

```
buildTypes {

     release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        zipAlignEnabled true
    }
}
```

**Note:** Older versions use `zipAlign`, instead of `zipAlignEnabled`

Default gradle tasks always created for debug and release buildTypes whether you define or not. Debug is for debugging purpose and Release for Signed Application **(Build >> Generate Signed Apk)**. You must define your signingConfig for release builds.

Check Build Types section in below mentioned link for other properties that you can use in your buildTypes

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide

Comment: Note that with the release of Android Studio 1.0 `runProguard` should be changed to `minifyEnabled`.

Comment: I have add `zipAlignEnabled true` but the Developer Console keeps telling me the apk-file is not zip aligned.

Comment: Be careful, the correctly zip aligned file is not in the buikd/output/apk directory but in the app directory directly. I've spent time on this!

Comment: @pyus13 Anybody knows what is the default value of zipAlign ? If we are not writing it then it is false or true.

Comment: I tried `zipAlignEnabled false`, but the apk was still zip aligned.

Comment: Same here @KimiChiu. How do I disable it?

Answer (score 6):

If you have created an `.apk` file (release mode) from Android Studio, your APK is already aligned. The `zipalign` step is part of the [Build Process in Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html).

You can check an APK with:

```
zipalign -c -v 4 {APP}.apk
```

To align an APK, run:

```
zipalign -v 4 {APP}.apk {ZIPALIGNED_APP}.apk
```

Comment: Android Studio was creating non-zip aligned release mode .apk files for me by default!

Answer (score 4):

Set classpath from
 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha3'
to

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'

Comment: Any time. :) @herrmarte

Answer (score 2):

**For complete signing process do follow steps. (Zip align manually after build- signed apk)**

**Step 0:** Before sign apk add code in your app module.gradle file : set zippAlignEnable and minifyEnable true.

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            //zipAlignEnabled true 
           //uncomment for automatically zip aligned by studio
        }
    }
```

**Step 1:** Sign your APK, relese mode [more info](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html)

**Step 2:** find location :  .\your sdk\build-tools\24.0.0

**Step 3:** **copy** your .jks keystore file and signed APK then **paste** it here.

**Step 4:** open command prompt (For windows). **set path.** of your location where you 
paste stuff.

**Step 5:** type command:   **`zipalign -f -v 4 infile.apk outfile.apk`**

here infile is my signed apk and outfile is file which is uploaded on play store.

**Done...!**

If cmp will got BUILD failed.

[See here for more about error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37783751/android-apk-not-zip-aligned-when-uploading-to-google-play/37786864#37786864) (Zipalign build failed) do following

1) Restart and open Android Studio,

2) close cmd, then reopen it.

3) Now do above process.

Edit:
resources.arsc BAD-1 error found

```
 set classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha3'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
```

**Happy Release**   :)

Comment: Mac users: 5) ./zipalign -f -v 4 infile.apk outfile.apk

Comment: I tried the same but getting error while installing align_apk, could you please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46462718/2624806).

Answer (score 1):

zipalign is in `ADT/sdk/build-tools/android4.4W`

1. Copy `android4.4W` folder
2. Paste it in `yourproject/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk`
3. Now, copy `yourkey.keystore and your project.apk`
4. Paste them into `android4.4W` full path

   `yourproject/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android4.4W`
5. then, `$ zipalign -v 4 project.apk wowdone.apk`.

Visit for more details: http://prehow.com/convert-wordpress-to-android-app-tutorial.html

Thats all, hope this answer will help you.

Comment: I did not found any android4.4W folder in specified location.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

1. Copy the last version folder 22.0.1 to yourproject/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk (like version 22.0.1 is my last version)
2. Copy yourkey.keystore and your project.apk into this verison folder 22.0.1.
3. Under the path yourproject/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/22.0.1, run this command:

   ```
   zipalign -v 4 name_of_current.apk name_of_wanted.apk
   ```
4. The name_of_wanted.apk should be located under yourproject/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/22.0.1