# How to zip Align APK file in android?

Tags: android, google-play, apk, publishing, zipalign

I am uploading my first APK file to google play but I am getting following error.

> You uploaded an APK that is not zip aligned. You will need to run a zip align tool on your APK and upload it again.

Can any one tell me how to zip align my apk file ?

Please tell me steps for that ?

Comment: Did you checked this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320526/how-to-zipalign-the-apk-file-using-eclipse

Comment: You need to use `zipalign [-f] [-v] <alignment> infile.apk outfile.apk` for that.

Comment: ok where I can do that?

Comment: In `Command prompt`....

Comment: Acctully I had followed the steps and ignore all errors but still I am getting same message

Comment: @LuckyyNickey No. I think you didn't use it proper way.

Comment: What is alignment? @PiYusHGuPtA

Comment: Ohk then what can I do now???? acctully I had already done this now Can I overrite this one?

Comment: You just need  to use that way fixed which can be converted your source apk to new destination apk with zip

Comment: Hey Now I have verification successfull.. Now?? @PiYusHGuPtA

Comment: @LuckyyNickey Now you have just use your destination apk and upload it to Google play if you have done all process.

Comment: Its the only proccess? do I need to Right Click on Project Folder->Android_Tools->Export Signed Application Package...

Comment: HEy       
Please see my edited question I am getting error in uploading

Answer (score 14):

Read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) from Google itself

The steps should be simple to follow.

Please follow **[this](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/preparing.html)** doc from google for complete publishing details

In short,complete steps in a nutshell(I am assuming you use eclipse/android sdk):

```
 1. Check android_manifest.xml and verify that android:debuggable  attribute is set to false in your manifest file            
 2. Check the android:versionCode and android:versionName attributes. 
    (if this is the first time you are uploading a apk,   
    ignore, else if it is a new version of existing apk, make sure these   
    values are larger than previous apk)
 3. Export unsigned application package from Eclipse
 4. Sign the application using release key certificate(not debug key certificate)
 5. Zip align the package
 6. Upload in google play
```

Comment: Hey Now I have verification successfull.. Now?

Comment: congrats.. so you have signed the apk and then zip aligned it right? Now go ahead and upload it in google play :)

Comment: yes.. and let me know once you are done/face any issues

Comment: Hey I am getting Error.. "You uploaded a debuggable APK. For security reasons you need to disable debugging before it can be published in Google Play. Learn more about debuggable APKs.
You uploaded an APK that was signed in debug mode. You need to sign your APK in release mode. Learn more about signing."

Comment: updated my answer. Please read the link to doc I mentioned carefully. Its complete and perfect.

Comment: Ok thanks Do i need to export unsigned APK file? acctully I had export signed apk file

Comment: yes you need to export unsigned apk file, and then sign it separately with a release certificate(if u export signed one, eclipse will sign with a debug certificate only, and google play doesn't like debug certificates)

Comment: "You uploaded an APK that was signed in debug mode. You need to sign your APK in release mode. Learn more about signing." How to debug to relese mode

Answer (score 13):

If you use Eclipse export wizard, it will automatically align it for you. However you can do it manually yourself

To align infile.apk and save it as outfile.apk:

```
zipalign [-f] [-v] <alignment> infile.apk outfile.apk
```

This website can provide more answers :) http://developer.android.com/tools/help/zipalign.html

Comment: Hmm what is alignmend?

Comment: Hey Now I have verification successfull.. Now what to do?

Comment: Hey I am getting error while uploading.       
Please see my edited question

Comment: <alignment> must always be 4

Comment: @LuckyyNickey: Please ask a different question rather than editing your solved question.

Comment: The <alignment> is an integer that defines the byte-alignment boundaries. This must always be 4 (which provides 32-bit alignment) or else it effectively does nothing.

Answer (score 10):

try below link or code:-

To align infile.apk and save it as outfile.apk:

```
zipalign [-f] [-v] <alignment> infile.apk outfile.apk
```

To confirm the alignment of existing.apk:

```
zipalign -c -v <alignment> existing.apk
```

The  is an integer that defines the byte-alignment boundaries. This must always be 4 (which provides 32-bit alignment) or else it effectively does nothing.

Flags:

```
-f : overwrite existing outfile.zip
-v : verbose output
-c : confirm the alignment of the given file
```

http://loomsdk.com/forums/loom-with-loomscript/topics/uploading-apk-to-google-play-displays-error-not-zip-aligned

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/zipalign.html

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ReRCJgS-g9o

Comment: Hey thanks but I am getting the error.       
Please see my edited question

Comment: @LuckyyNickey see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19994874/unable-to-upload-new-apk-file-to-android-play-store

Answer (score 4):

Check the`manifest.xml` file in your project it should say something like this:

```
android:debuggable="true"
```

set it to `"false"`.

Answer (score 3):

If you use eclipse the easiest way is to do it directly from it.

Go to "File" -> "Export" -> "Android Application Export"

[image: Select Android Application Export]

The tool would ask you if you already have a keystore, if you do use it if not create a new one and save it on a safe place (you must remember the password so be sure to keep it somewhere you cannot lose it).

Then upload the file and there should be no errors.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and tried all of the hints that are listed here but not cigar, I thought it was a bug but all my other Apps would work is just one of them had the issue e.g. after passing the not zip align I'd get You uploaded a debuggable apk.  I was generating the apk from Eclipse/Indigo and the problem was the last step where it specifies the apk path somehow was pointing to some subdirectory had no idea how that one got in there, but using the proper path took care of it.