# how to Zipalign apk without eclipse

Tags: android, apk

i wanna ask about : 
how to zipalign apk app without eclipse or coding because i have an apk file i make with non eclipse ..but when i upload to google play it say :
You uploaded an APK that is not zip aligned. You will need to run a zip align tool on your APK and upload it again.
i try some apps to zipalign the apk without coding but it doesn't work for me...

### i need a way to zipalign the apk easily without coding or eclipse have any idea ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to zip Align APK file in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23333724/how-to-zip-align-apk-file-in-android)

Comment: But this for eclipse I need a way without coding

Comment: You don't have to code. You need to use the `zipalign` tool provided in the Android SDK.

Comment: where can i find it please help still new to java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are working on a Linux based environment, like Ubuntu.

You can find the `zipaling` tool in the path `android-sdk/build-tools/{higher version you can find}/zipalign`, where `android-sdk` is the folder where you have the Android SDK. For example: `android-sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/zipalign`

And then, to use it:

`android-sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/zipalign 4 infile.apk outfile.apk`

Where `infile.apk` is your unaligned apk file, and `outfile.apk` is the aligned output of the tool

Comment: FATAL: [SignApksBuilder] zipalign failed: exit code 1
ERROR: zipalign failed on APK /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/PP_androidBuild/PatientPortal/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk: exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE

Comment: manually its working but failing under jenkins builds as shown above

Comment: jenkins@ip-172-31-22-20:~$  /opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.1/zipalign -f -p 4 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/PP_androidBuild/PatientPortal/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/PP_androidBuild/SignApksBuilder-out/zipalign/aligned-android-debug-6100835664895780913.apk

Comment: jenkins@ip-172-31-22-20:~$ ls -lthr /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/PP_androidBuild/SignApksBuilder-out/zipalign/aligned-android-debug-6100835664895780913.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins 5.9M Sep  8 14:09 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/PP_androidBuild/SignApksBuilder-out/zipalign/aligned-android-debug-6100835664895780913.apk