# zipalign stalling when finishing signing process of Android app

Tags: android, bash, cordova, signing

I'm trying to run zipalign to finish the signing process of my Android app, but it just hangs up there forever without any output.

I've left it for over 30 min and nothing comes back. Any suggestions? Is it possible to re-install it individually? is there an alternative?

I'm running OSX 10.9.4.

UPDATE #1:

Tried re-installing the Android SDK Platform-tools, but still seeing the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run zipalign successfully by executing it directly from the build-tools directory.

In my case, the zipalign executable that worked fine was under `/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/r20.0.3/build-tools/20.0.0/zipalign`. Using that executable got my app signed in less than 10 seconds.

Then I just created a symlink so I could simply do `zipalign` in my terminal:

```
ln -sf /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/r20.0.3/build-tools/20.0.0/zipalign /usr/local/bin/zipalign
```

For those that have never seen zipalign working (like me), it takes a couple of seconds to run completely for my app (~8MB) and it outputs the files that are being compressed:

```
$ zipalign -v 4 MyAwesomeApp-release-unsigned.apk MyAwesomeApp.apk
Verifying alignment of MyAwesomeApp.apk (4)...
      50 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF (OK - compressed)
    9974 META-INF/GGRGOOGL.SF (OK - compressed)
   20132 META-INF/GGRGOOGL.RSA (OK - compressed)
   21317 assets/www/css/fonts/ITCAvantGardeStd-Bk.otf (OK - compressed)
   44346 assets/www/css/fonts/ITCAvantGardeStd-BkCn.otf (OK - compressed)
   67341 assets/www/css/fonts/ITCAvantGardeStd-BkCnObl.otf (OK - compressed)
   ....
 6717884 res/drawable-port-mdpi/screen.png (OK)
 6810380 res/drawable-port-xhdpi/screen.png (OK)
 7311427 classes.dex (OK - compressed)
Verification succesful
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the command prompt to make a zip align apk. Here is the reference link that I find very Useful.

[How to zipalign the .apk file using eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320526/how-to-zipalign-the-apk-file-using-eclipse)